# Continuous or discontinuous function

Tags: calculus, limits

let $f(x) =(\sqrt x + \sqrt{x+1})x$

This function exist at right hand limit at point $0$.

So can we say it continuous or discontinuous at point $0$.

Comment: What did you try?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your function is defined on $[0,\infty)$ and the limit:
$$\lim_{x\to 0^+} f(x) = 0 $$
exits and takes the same value as $f(0)=0$ so your function is continuous at $x=0$, as you can't define another limit ( $x\to0^-$ for example.)

Coming back to the definition of continuity, for it to not be continuous at $0$ you must have a value $\epsilon>0$ for which you can't find a value $\delta$ such that if $x<\delta$ then $f(x)<\epsilon$.
Why am I not puting absolute values? because of the domain of definition of the function, I can only considere non negative values of $x$.

So finally, as your function is only defined on the non negative real axis, the definition of continuity holds on $0$ (you can't find such $\epsilon$) and therefore your function is continuous at $0$